I want to match the city with the maximum percentage using googlesheet
Okay so I have this full table, with column D as city and column K as percentage. Now, city has many rows, which is why i only want the city with the highest percentage.
I tried using Query:
=QUERY(FILTER('Sheet1'!A:M, 'Vision List'!F:F <> "Approved"), "SELECT Col4, MAX(Col11) GROUP BY Col4 ORDER BY Col4 ASC", 1)

And try to match the city and percentage from sheet1 with this query. But no luck in getting all the rows. I used arrayformula with match, which one gave one row. I used filter but it says that

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1000. column count: 1. Actual row count: 999, column count: 1.


Supply an example .CSV of the data you're working with.

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1000. column count: 1. Actual row count: 999, column count: 1 This error means you do not have same number of in in Sheet1 and Vision List. Make row number same. Other should work fine.

Other should work fine. @Harun24hr I agree that the error is caused by a row mismatch but (and I am no expert) I've never seen an example of FILTER where the range is on one sheet and the condition/criterion is on another sheet.

Please edit the question to include sample data and example(s) of successful outcomes.

@Harun24hr Consider adding it as answer. Explanatory answers are valuable than code only answers.

@Tedinoz It will work. FILTER() only work based on TRUE/FALSE whatever data is in same sheet or on other sheet. So, when  this part 'Vision List'!F:F <> "Approved" will return true that row will be filtered.

Argh, EBKAC. @Harun24hr is 100% correct. I have re-tested, fixed my appallingly stupid, simple mistake and the filter DOES work with references to multiple sheets.


FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1000. column count: 1. Actual row count: 999, column count: 1.

Above error means you do not have same number of rows in both sheet. One sheet have 1000 rows and another sheet have 999 rows. So, add 1 row more to make same number of rows in both sheet.
FILTER() works based on TRUE/FALSE whatever data is in same sheet or on other sheet. So, when this part 'Vision List'!F:F <> "Approved" will return true, those rows will be filtered.
You query part "SELECT Col4, MAX(Col11) GROUP BY Col4 ORDER BY Col4 ASC" seems fine.
